# Need To Remove space from String "I N P U T W O R D"Using Java

Tags: java

I want to remove space from the below string.

```
String name= "I n p u t   T e x t";
```

Can someone please suggest how to remove the spaces?

I have solution only to remove spaces between the string not between the char

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(filepath);
     ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

     while(scan.hasNext()){
         String curLine = scan.nextLine();
         String[] splitted = curLine.split("\t");
         for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
         {
          String name = splitted[i].
          System.out.println(name);
         }
         
     }

Comment: Use `name.replace(" ","");` maybe?

Comment: @user23050 Next time, please [edit] the post. Comments are not meant for code

Comment: How about `String name = "InputText";`?

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
String name= "I n p u t   T e x t";
String namenew = name.replaceAll("\\s+","");
System.out.println(name);
System.out.println(namenew);
```

Cheers !

Comment: I tried this but still its not working

Comment: What is the output ?

Comment: If you tried this, of course it didn't work. There's a missing critical piece.

Comment: Its giving the below outputI n p u t   T e x t

Comment: Please see updated answer you need to assign it to a variable.